# Deserialize returns object with all values set to null

Tags: c#, json, json.net

```
String str ="{\"_id\":\"eta_emp_1\",\"_rev\":\"446-195e9341df50aeed33d2cb833420b100\",";
str+="\"channels\":[\"ch_pri-eta_org\"],\"doc_type\":\"emp\",\"downloaded\":true,";
str+="\"eta_code\":\"abhi\",\"f_name\":\"Abhilash\",\"isactive\":true,";
str+="\"isadmin\":true,\"l_name\":\"Dhondalkar\",";
str+="\"lat\":17.69967582522918,\"lon\":75.89857880026102,";
str+="\"m_name\":\"Dheeraj\",\"mod_at\":1494693566503,\"mod_by\":\"eta_emp_1\",";
str+="\"org_id\":\"eta_org\",\"pwd\":\"abcde\",";
str+="\"reported_by\":[\"e27f41e7-5b84-4c86-838e-97598b4d20a0\",\"8daa0901-f6e8-4fdd-b41c-658aa901899d\",";
str+="\"9bf72297-481c-4d59-a0f4-d5549cb60e27\",\"2e5ce994-2cfb-4e62-88f8-ff1d3a069ca0\"]}";

UserDetails userDetails = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserDetails>(str);



 public class UserDetails
    {

    String _id{get;set;}
    String _rev { get; set; }
    String[] channels{get;set;} 
    String doc_type{get;set;} 
    bool downloaded{get;set;} 
    String eta_code{get;set;} 
    String f_name{get;set;}
    bool isactive { get; set; }
    bool isadmin { get; set; } 
    long l_name{get;set;}
    long lat{get;set;}
    String lon{get;set;}
    String m_name{get;set;}
    long mod_at{get;set;} 
    String mod_by{get;set;}
    String org_id{get;set;}
    String pwd{get;set;} 
    String[] reported_by{get;set;}
    }
```

All values are set to null.
Not able to figure out issue. Pl help

Comment: where do you get your `string` from? Normally when deserializing / serializing you should not need to use `str +=` since it usually is only one `string`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This class should work:

```
public class UserDetails
{
        public string _id { get; set; }
        public string _rev { get; set; }
        public List<string> channels { get; set; }
        public string doc_type { get; set; }
        public bool downloaded { get; set; }
        public string eta_code { get; set; }
        public string f_name { get; set; }
        public bool isactive { get; set; }
        public bool isadmin { get; set; }
        public string l_name { get; set; }
        public double lat { get; set; }
        public double lon { get; set; }
        public string m_name { get; set; }
        public long mod_at { get; set; }
        public string mod_by { get; set; }
        public string org_id { get; set; }
        public string pwd { get; set; }
        public List<string> reported_by { get; set; }
}
```

More help:

http://json2csharp.com

Based on my previous experience with JSON.NET, it can be a bit tricky the translation from JSON to the right class. The web site above have provided me all the time the right class. The only exception is the Wikipedia API because it's a dynamic API and you need to do a small trick.

Also, keep in mind all properties **must be public** because if something is private (like in your question), it is not going to be accessible by the translator or anything else. I hope it's helpful.

Comment: Changing from array to list helps?

Comment: is it because of properties need to be `public` in order to be serialized @Federico Navarrete ?

Comment: Hi @ThFI, yes all properties must be public if something is not, it won't be able to find it, but I strongly suggest the website: json2csharp.com, it's less problematic.

Comment: @FedericoNavarrete alright, thank you for that tip and the Website. This should be the accepted answer

Comment: My bad, just stupid mistake !! and publicly publishing it!!

Answer (score 1):

Either mark all the properties in your class as public, or explicity add JsonProperty attribute to each property as follows:

```
public class UserDetails
    {
        [JsonProperty("_id")]
        String _id { get; set; }

        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When using [Json Validator](http://www.json-validator.com) I got "The root JSON data must represent an object or an array", therefore indicating that your JSON is most likey not correct. 
This is why the `string` cannot be serialized to your class, leaving the properties `null`.
You should show us your serialization process to find out about where the error is.

Comment: The string is response of a rest call. When I do Quick watch on str, and see value in Json visualizer, it shows perfectly. I even checked the json in online json viewer. It is perfectly fine.

Comment: Is this `str` content exactly what you are receiving?

Comment: @DheerajDhondalkar alright, just a guess. Check if Federico Navarretes answer works for you :)

Comment: Here is response from rest call  {"_id":"eta_emp_1","_rev":"446-195e9341df50aeed33d2cb833420b100","channels":["ch_pri-eta_org"],"doc_type":"emp","downloaded":true,"eta_code":"abhi","f_name":"Abhilash","isactive":true,"isadmin":true,"l_name":"Dhondalkar","lat":17.69967582522918,"lon":75.89857880026102,"m_name":"Dheeraj","mod_at":1494693566503,"mod_by":"eta_emp_1","org_id":"eta_org","pwd":"abcde","reported_by":["e27f41e7-5b84-4c86-838e-97598b4d20a0","8daa0901-f6e8-4fdd-b41c-658aa901899d","9bf72297-481c-4d59-a0f4-d5549cb60e27","2e5ce994-2cfb-4e62-88f8-ff1d3a069ca0"]}